# How to zoom image not using imageview in android?

Tags: android, zooming

I am working on client server application in android and want to zoom the image sent from client on server and get the zoomed image back. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebView if you don't want ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you dont want use imageview

Use TouchImageView 
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

```
<com.luminous.pick.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I hope it will help you..